# Blue screen error in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, debug, hard-drive, dump

I have Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and keep getting a blue screen error. I think it has something to do with my hard drive, but I'm not sure if it is failing or not.

Here is the .dmp debug:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\120311-11512-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.17640.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02e12000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03057670
Debug session time: Sat Dec  3 19:10:59.133 2011 (UTC - 6:00)
System Uptime: 2 days 0:27:09.007
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
..................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.....
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck F4, {3, fffffa8008ed02b0, fffffa8008ed0590, fffff800031928b0}

Probably caused by : csrss.exe

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4)
A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been
terminated.
Several processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the
system; when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no
longer function.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, Process
Arg2: fffffa8008ed02b0, Terminating object
Arg3: fffffa8008ed0590, Process image file name
Arg4: fffff800031928b0, Explanatory message (ascii)

Debugging Details:
------------------


PROCESS_OBJECT: fffffa8008ed02b0

IMAGE_NAME:  csrss.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MODULE_NAME: csrss

FAULTING_MODULE: 0000000000000000 

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000006 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of 0x%x.

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF4_IOERR

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`05280e38 fffff800`032195e2 : 00000000`000000f4 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`08ed02b0 fffffa80`08ed0590 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`05280e40 fffff800`031c699b : ffffffff`ffffffff fffffa80`0941ea00 fffffa80`08ed02b0 fffffa80`08ed02b0 : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x92
fffff880`05280e80 fffff800`03146448 : ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`08ed02b0 00000000`00000008 : nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x176d6
fffff880`05280ed0 fffff800`02e8ded3 : fffffa80`08ed02b0 fffff800`c0000006 fffffa80`0941ea00 00000000`02380980 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0xf4
fffff880`05280f50 fffff800`02e8a470 : fffff800`02eda67f fffff880`05281a38 fffff880`05281790 fffff880`05281ae0 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
fffff880`052810e8 fffff800`02eda67f : fffff880`05281a38 fffff880`05281790 fffff880`05281ae0 00000000`02381690 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
fffff880`052810f0 fffff800`02e8e2c2 : fffff880`05281a38 00000000`00011a44 fffff880`05281ae0 00000000`02381168 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x49874
fffff880`05281900 fffff800`02e8ce3a : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`fde1d8b4 fffffa80`08d59c01 00000000`00011a44 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xc2
fffff880`05281ae0 00000000`779a9c12 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x23a
00000000`023810b0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x779a9c12


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xF4_IOERR_IMAGE_csrss.exe

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xF4_IOERR_IMAGE_csrss.exe

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Did this happen after a new installation? If not, what did you do last on that computer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is specifically to do with your hard drive, but here is an article to help you understand what `CSRSS.EXE` does and how to deal with errors from that process.

[What is csrss.exe?](http://www.processlibrary.com/directory/files/csrss/26031/)

It is possible a virus may be exploiting this process, so make sure you run scans to verify your system is clean.